# May printf (or fprintf or dprintf) return ("successfully") less (but nonnegative) than the number of "all bytes"?

Tags: c, printf, return-value

The manual says that

> Upon successful return, these functions [printf, dprintf etc.] return the number of characters printed.

The manual does **not** mention whethet may this number less (but yet nonnegative) than the length of the "final" (substitutions and formattings done) string. Nor mentions that how to check whether (or achieve that) the string was *completely* written.

The dprintf function operates on file descriptor. Similarily to the *write* function, for which the manual **does** mention that

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates nothing was written). It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;

So if I want to write a string completely then I have to enclose the `n = write()` in a while-loop. Should I have to do the same in case of *dprintf* or *printf*?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you call `printf` for a second time with the same format specifiers and arguments? The return value is for information (or an error). The only way you could check the correct output of `printf` is by first calling `sprintf`, but there could be a difference in the handling of `newline`.

Comment: What is your use case? What is the file descriptor used for? What protocol does it carry?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) is that `dprintf` would either fail or output all the output. But I agree that it is some gray area (and I might not understand well); I'm *guessing* that a partial output is some kind of failure (so returns a negative size).

Here is the implementation of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/):

In [stdio/dprintf.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/dprintf.c) the `dprintf` function just calls `vdprintf`

But in [stdio/vdprintf.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vdprintf.c) you just have:

```
static size_t wrap_write(FILE *f, const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    return __stdio_write(f, buf, len);
}

int vdprintf(int fd, const char *restrict fmt, va_list ap)
{
    FILE f = {
        .fd = fd, .lbf = EOF, .write = wrap_write,
        .buf = (void *)fmt, .buf_size = 0,
        .lock = -1
    };
    return vfprintf(&f, fmt, ap);
}
```

So `dprintf` is returning a size like `vfprintf` (and `fprintf`....) does.

However, if you really are concerned, you'll better use `snprintf`  or `asprintf`  to output into some memory buffer, and explicitly use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) on that buffer.

Look into [stdio/__stdio_write.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/__stdio_write.c) the implementation of `__stdio_write` (it uses [writev(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2.html) with a vector of two data chunks in a loop).

In other words, I would often not really care; but if you really need to be sure that every byte has been written as you expect it (for example if the file descriptor is some HTTP socket), I would suggest to buffer *explicitly* (e.g. by calling `snprintf` and/or `asprintf`) yourself, then use your explicit [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).

<sup>PS. You might check yourself the source code of *your* particular C standard library providing `dprintf`; for GNU glibc see notably [libio/iovdprintf.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iovdprintf.c;hb=HEAD)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With stdio, returning the number of partially written bytes doesn't make much sense because stdio functions work with a (more or less) global buffer whose state is unknown to you and gets dragged in from previous calls.

If stdio functions allowed you to work with that, the error return values would need to be more complex as they would not only need to communicate how many characters were or were not outputted, but also whether the failure was before your last input somewhere in the buffer, or in the middle of your last input and if so, how much of the last input got buffered.

The d-functions could theoretically give you the number of partially written characters easy, but POSIX specifies that they should mirror the stdio functions and so they only give you a further unspecified negative value on error.

If you need more control, you can use the lower level functions.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `printf()`, it is quite clear.

> The `printf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.  C11dr §7.21.6.3 3

A negative value is returned if an error occurred.  In that case 0 or more characters may have printed.  The count is unknowable via the standard library.

If the value return is not negative, that is the number sent to `stdout`.

Since `stdout` is often buffered, that may not be the number received at the output device on the conclusion of `printf()`.  Follow `printf()` with a `fflush(stdout)`

```
int r1 = printf(....);
int r2 = fflush(stdout);
if (r1 < 0 || r2 != 0) Handle_Failure();
```

For finest control, "print" to a buffer and use `putchar()` or various non-standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that **no**. (After looking into the - obfuscated - source of *printf*.)  So **any** nonnegative return value means that printf was **fully** succesful (reached the end of the format string, everything was passed to kernel buffers).
But some (authentic) people should confirm it.